# Adding additional evidence after submitting an application for a UK short-term study visa

Tags: united-kingdom

I applied recently for a short term study visa to join a summer School at an English university. I submitted the following document:

- The invitation from the university in England, confirming that I have paid the fees of the summer School which inclined the accommodation.
- A letter from my supervisor confirming that I am working at his institute as a phd researcher.
- my residency permission in Germany which is valid for more three years.
- my passport.
- a flight ticket.

I unfortunately didn't submit my bank statement. The employee of the visa center didn't ask about it and I thought it is not required. I am very surprised to see online in many forums how important it is. Well my question, do you believe that what I have submitted can be enough to get a short study visa? Can I add a bank statement to my application, although I can see that my application has been sent from Germany to the UK?

Answer (score 1):

It may be sufficient, as your program is brief and within the sort of time frames given for other, general visitors and which allow some studies. It may be too late to amend the application, as it is no longer at the Consulate, but you can ask.

Like you, many fail to notice an important link in the overview on how to apply for a UK visa, that for **[supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents)**:

> ## [Documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide)
>
> When you apply you’ll need to provide:
>
> - a current passport or other valid travel identification
> - evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, such as bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months
>
> **Read the [full list of supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) you can provide.**
>
> You might need to provide additional documents if you’re visiting the UK:
>
> - for private medical treatment
> - to apply as an organ donor
> - as an academic on sabbatical and want to stay for 12 months
> - as a prospective entrepreneur
> - to take the Professional and Linguistic Assessment Board (PLAB) test or sit the Objective Structured Clinical Examination (OSCE)

First published in 2012, annually updated (and with a added Chinese translation), this seven-page guide responds to many, if not all, of the most frequent queries.

In just one page, it outlines fundamental documents:

> ### Section 2: other documents you may want to provide – all visitors
>
> This section provides guidance on the types of documents that you may want to provide to help us consider your application against the Immigration Rules.
>
> Previous travel documents/passports, which show previous travel.
>
> Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>
> - bank statements
> - building society book
> - proof of earnings such as a letter from employer confirming employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company contact details)
> - where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support to you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show they have sufficient resources to support you in addition to themselves and any dependant family should be
>     provided
>
> Confirmation of legal residence, if you are not a national of the country in which you are applying or your right to reside there is not included in your passport.
>
> Details of employment or studies where you have stated in your application that you are either employed or in full-time studies. This could include:
>
> - a letter from your employer on company headed paper, detailing your role,
> - salary and length of employment
> - a letter from your education provider, on headed paper, confirming your enrolment and leave of absence
>
> If self employed: business registration documents confirming the business owner’s name and the date the business started trading.
>
> Business activities – where you are coming to the UK in order to undertake activities relating to your occupation/employment outside the UK you should submit documents showing what you will be doing in the UK, including any letters from inviting organisations. For example:
>
> - any business activities, e.g. letter from your employer outlining the reason for your visit, who you will be meeting and details of any payment/expenses
> - for performances and entertainment visitors, whether you work in this area as a professional or amateur , and what and where you will be performing
>
> Under 18s – we strongly recommend you submit the following information otherwise it may delay consideration of your application.
>
> - a Birth Certificate or legal document (such as adoption papers) showing the relationship between you and your parent or guardian If travelling unaccompanied or with someone other than your parent(s) you should
>     provide:
> - a signed letter from your parent(s) confirming details of anyone accompanying you, and details of care and accommodation arranged in the UK
> - a copy of your parent(s) or legal guardian’s biographical page of their passport, which includes their signature and passport number if your parent(s) do not
>     have a passport then you must provide another official document which bears their signature

What follows (Section 3) are additional documents for  specific visitor types:

- academics coming to undertake research (12 month visa)
- family accompanying academic coming to undertake research (12 month visa)
- private medical treatment
- organ donors
- prospective entrepreneur
- work related training
- performers at permit free festivals
- Approved Destination Scheme
- permitted paid engagements
- visitor (marriage/civil partnership)
- transit

Section 4 lists documents that ***should not be sent*** to support applications.